# pyautogui: Hover events not triggered on Windows

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, automation, pyautogui

I am using Python 3.x with the library pyautogui. When I move the mouse to the windows icon on the taskbar, the icon changes its color (because of the hover event). Then I click on it to open the menu.

Now to my problem:

After moving the mouse with `pyautogui.moveto(x, y)`, the mouse cursor is above the Firefox symbol, BUT no hovering is triggered (see attached screenshot). Only after I move the mouse by hand, it is triggered and highlighted.

Is this a bug? How could I fix this?

[image: no_hover_event_with_pyautogui]

Comment: Will the hover effect be triggered if you use ```pyautogui.moveto(x, y, pyautogui.easeOutQuad)``` ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly it did not help. Even when I move the curser super slow, it does not trigger. I recorded a video and uploaded it: https://imgur.com/a/P5of3Ja (Video is in realtime, just not enough frames :) ). You can see that even the buttons on the left (Power, Settings) are slightly getting highlighted, just not the menu entries.

Comment: I think that might be the issue here. The fact that it hops and it jitters onto the location and not _smooothly_ like when you do it by hand. You could use [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases). Maybe that library will be better for this.

Answer (score 0):

A similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473989/how-application-get-mouse-movement-when-using-pyautogui) describes this same issue with the calculator. This is a bug, most likely from the windows api itself, see reported issue [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/314). A solution was found, but it was not implemented and the bug still persists.
I can reproduce the error on windows with Python 3.6.8 and pyautogui 0.9.50 with the following code:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('win')
pyautogui.moveTo(200, 820, duration=3)
pyautogui.scroll(-900)
```

See video [here](https://youtu.be/Ek91sjpoJHQ). I changed the source of pyautogui to the suggested solution in the post and it works.

**Solution:**

1. Fork the pyautogui code repository on github
2. Implement the solution mentioned on [issue 314](https://youtu.be/Ek91sjpoJHQ)
3. Uninstall pyautogui
4. Reinstall pyautogui from source from the forked repository

**Note:** This is just a tweak and remember that the pyautogui maintainer decided not to make this implementation for a reason. Therefore make sure at some point you reinstall the official version again.